# Pi GPIO - momentary open switch for shutdown - python help needed for time delay

Tags: gpio, python

I have a python script working that will shutdown the raspberry pi when I close a momentary switch, using the RPi.GPIO interrupts.  However as soon as the switch is closed the pi shuts down.  Is there a way to program in a time function i.e. only shutdown the pi with the momentary switch is closed for 2 seconds?  I am trying to avoid accidental bumps of the shutdown switch.

Thanks!

Here is my script:

```
import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING)
subprocess.call(['shutdown -h now "System halted by GPIO action"'], shell=True)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
buttonReleased = True
while buttonReleased:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING)
    # button has been pressed
    buttonReleased = False
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if GPIO.input(17):
            buttonReleased = True
            break

GPIO.cleanup()
subprocess.call(...
```

Comment: This will shut down the system if the button is pressed for more than 0.1second, not 2 seconds. If you put the `buttonReleased = True` after the for loop, it should only trigger if button is pressed for at least 2 seconds.

Comment: No, if it's pressed for less than 2 seconds and then released, it goes back to waiting for the falling edge. Bonus is that it doesn't get fooled by two presses 2 seconds apart.

Comment: Sorry. I stand corrected. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
while True:
  GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING)
  time.sleep(2)
  if GPIO.input(17)==False:
    subprocess.call(['shutdown -h now "System halted by GPIO action"'], shell=True)
    break

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Somewhat crude version that only check is the button is still pressed after 2 seconds.

Comment: I don't think it will like doing a `GPIO.wait_for_edge` after the `GPIO.cleanup()`.  Of course the system is shutting down anyway so I guess it wouldn't matter too much!

Comment: True. See edit above.